# Textblock modify text automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have two `TextBlock` on the same page and both binding to the same variable:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding [someViewModel].someText}/>
<TextBlock Text={Binding [someViewModel].someText}/>

//someText = "testingText"
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the first textblock to show "tes......" and the second textblock showing "testingText"?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Is it your primary intention?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I've no idea how to elaborate more to improve my question. lol.

Comment: Is it your business goal to have 2 such textblocks?

Comment: Yeap. At the same time.

Comment: Good luck :) See the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="testingtext" MaxWidth="20" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="testingtext" ></TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
```

output

[image]

Comment: I've tried your way. What happened was there wasn't any "..." but it expand to the next line instead.

tes<br/>
ting<br/>
tex<br/>

Comment: run this code separately you will get same result and make sure that you are not using Textwrapping because textrapping will do line break(next line)

Answer (score 1):

Make an `IValueConverter` for one of the bindings which converts the String to the custom format you want.